# why is this failing 'undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass' rspec rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

The idea of this test is to handle the event a record is not found. There for a destroy action should not take place and yet it is. I've chopped and changed it around, nut essentially the test reads right, so there must be a problem in my code.

```
RSpec.describe Admin::EntriesController, :type => :controller do

  setup_factories

  let(:model){ Photo }
  let(:instance){photo}
  let(:no_instances){no_photos}
  let(:some_instances){some_photos}
  let(:params_full_instance){params_full_photo}
  let(:params_new_instance){params_new_photo}

describe "delete destroy" do
      context "where the record is found" do
        before do
          allow(model).to receive(:where).and_return(some_instances)
          allow(some_instances).to receive(:first).and_return(instance)
        end
        context "where the record is destroyed" do
          before do
            allow(instance).to receive(:destroy).and_return(true)
            delete :destroy, params_id
          end
          sets_flash(:notice)
          redirects_to('/admin/entries/rejected')
        end
        context "where the record is not destroyed" do
          before do
            allow(instance).to receive(:destroy).and_return(false)
            delete :destroy, params_id
          end
          sets_flash(:error)
          redirects_to('/admin/entries/rejected')
        end
      end
      context "where the record is not found" do
        before do
          allow(model).to receive(:where).and_return(no_instances)
          delete :destroy, params_id

        end
        sets_flash(:error)
        redirects_to('/admin/entries/rejected')
      end
```

CONTROLLER

```
  before_action :get_entry_id, only: [:destroy, :toggle_approve_field, :toggle_reject_field]
    def destroy
       if @entry.nil?
          flash[:error] = "object is not not found"
        end
        if @entry.destroy
          flash[:notice] = 'blah'
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to rejected_admin_entries_path }
            format.json { head :no_content }
            format.js
          end
        else
          flash[:error] = 'There was a problem fetching the record'
          redirect_to rejected_admin_entries_path
        end
      end

    def get_entry_id
        if @entry.nil?
          flash[:error] = "object is not not found"
        end
        @entry = Photo.where(id: params[:id]).first
      end
```

I probably need a fresh pair of eyes on it. And a nice explanation as to what I am getting wrong ;)

UPDATE: expected behaviour, is, when a destroy action is made, and the record is not found, i expect to see a flash error and to be redirected.

UPDATE 2: Implemented guys code below, still receiving error

```
 1) Admin::EntriesController for authenticated users delete destroy where the record is not found should set flash error
     Failure/Error: expect(flash[method]).to_not be_nil
       expected: not nil
            got: nil
     # -e:1:in `<main>'

  2) Admin::EntriesController for authenticated users delete destroy where the record is not found should redirect to /admin/entries/rejected
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(path)
       Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
```

Thanks
Rico

Comment: You try to destroy the object even if it's nil.

Comment: @DaveNewton in which case it should throw an error, no?

Comment: It does; it's calling a method on nil. Please be specific regarding what behavior you *expect*. All the code does is add a flash message if it's nil, then it's going to throw the error since nil doesn't have a destroy method.

Comment: Same comment as before: you're trying to delete the object even if it's nil.

Comment: and if it is, an error shoudl be raised

Comment: ... An error *is* being raised. The problem is that you don't *handle* that error. All you do is set a flash message: your code continues merrily along, trying to delete the record. At that point, IMO, all bets are off regarding the view layer, although it's possible the flash check should still work. Also, your filter attempts to check `@entry` before trying to find it. I wouldn't do the flash check in the filter, either, but that's juts me.

Comment: OK I think I follow, so, how best do I handle such an error?

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for the edit ;) 'sub-optimal', i like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you are still trying @entry.destroy even if it is still nil.

```
def destroy
  if @entry.nil?
    flash[:error] = "object is not not found"
  elsif @entry.destroy
    flash[:notice] = 'blah'
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to rejected_admin_entries_path }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        format.js
    end
  else
    flash[:error] = 'There was a problem fetching the record'
    redirect_to rejected_admin_entries_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the destroy method. You are not calling return. This should work:

```
def destroy
   if @entry.nil?
      flash[:error] = "object is not not found"
      return
   end

   if @entry.destroy
      flash[:notice] = 'blah'
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to rejected_admin_entries_path }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        format.js
      end
   else
      flash[:error] = 'There was a problem fetching the record'
      redirect_to rejected_admin_entries_path
   end
  end
```

Anyway this code is sub-optimal. You should find the @entry in a before_filter aspect and return a 404 if is not found.

E.g.,

```
before_filter :find_entry

...

def find_entry
  @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: THANKS FOR THE ENCOURAGING COMMENTS DUDE, see updated answer, just added before filter